# Calling service values directly into directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I need to call the directive which will populate the data using ng-repeat from the service data.

The desired output will be

```
<ul>Days
<li>Monday</li>
<li>Tuesday</li>
...
<ul>
<ul>Month
<li>January</li>
<li>February</li>
...
<ul>
```

I created a jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/upzayfv1/8/

Upon on the directive is not called in my jsfiddle but the data "I am from directive" is displaying in my localhost. By running the jsfiddle you could get a betterview of my request.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to restrict your directive to "Element":

```
return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template:"adsf"
    }
```

Comment: alternately, you could do <div my-days></div> as opposed to <my-days></my-days>

Comment: It worked. But my question is how to display service data to directive.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't inject the service into your directive. Letting the controller decide what the directive's data will be is a lot more flexible. Here are my changes.

View:

```
<my-days weeks="daysListWeeks"></my-days>
```

Controller:

```
myapp.controller("daysController",function($scope,daysList){

    $scope.test = "I am from controller";
    $scope.daysListWeeks = daysList.weeks();
    console.log(daysList.weeks());
});
```

Directive:

```
myapp.directive("myDays",function(){

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { weeks: '='},
        template:"<ul><li ng-repeat='m in weeks'>{{m}}</li></ul>"
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you directive version would look like this, you could access the service inside the directive just by adding `daysList` in you directive function. Then access service function from directive `link` function & set the values in `scope`

**Directive**

```
 myapp.directive("myDays",function(daysList){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template:'<div ng-repeat="day in daysList">{{day}}</div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            console.log(daysList)
           scope.daysList = daysList.weeks().days;
        }
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/upzayfv1/8/)

Comment: I shall try this tomorrow and keep you posted